# The strange history of a question's votes

Tags: discussion, voting, specific-question

So I asked [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/382356/many-of-the-mobs-uses) and it has some interesting story of its votes which I find strange.

So I asked it, self-answered it as a CW, and let it be before I can accept the answer. For some time, it was negatively received, and I had no idea why. As it turns out, some decided to close vote it for needing more focus.

But after some time, it started to gain a positive move for some time, then later got closed. Soon then, a few others like the question and answer so they decided to reopen vote it, but some reason, the question got downvoted again after getting reopened in a few hours.

If you inspect my rep history and the history of my question, you'll noticed what had happened.

---

**TL;DR;** There's a question that got negatively-received, later getting closed and getting upvoted, later getting reopened then receiving a downvote.

Why has this become the case? Are there similar occurances?

Comment: Something else to quick note - I originally saw the question and voted to close in a queue, which only let me at first see the question and I only looked at the question, so I voted to close. However, I later saw it normally on the site and saw the answer - and changed my mind. (I think i was the first to vote to reopen and brought it into the queue, i dont remember). So I think something else to consider is the **context in which it was seen**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arqade is a community-moderated site, which means that we don't all act on the same set of principles - everyone has different tastes and ideas of how they would run the site. Sure, there are some things that the majority of the site agrees on, but even if we have 95% of users in agreement, that still means 5% of our users don't agree.

What you saw on that question is community moderation in practice - some people downvoted, some upvoted. Some people voted to close, because they thought the question needed "more focus", and others voted to reopen, because they thought it was fine. This is a fairly normal thing to occur and isn't something to be overly worried about.

Eventually the question will reach a sort of 'equilibrium state' - where the majority of active users have seen/interacted with the post and the question activity drops off. If you were receiving comments requesting more info, or if the question remained closed, this is when you would need to look at editing for clarification, or reduce the scope of the question (e.g. instead of asking about all mobs potential uses, ask about a particular mob that you're unsure about).